# All the roots of $5\cos x - \sin x = 4$ in the interval $0^{\circ} \leq x \leq 360^{\circ}$?

Tags: trigonometry

This is a problem that I stumbled upon in one of my books.

Representing $5\cos x - \sin x$ in the form $R\cos(x + \alpha)$ (as demanded by the question):

$
\rightarrow R = \sqrt{5^2 + ({-}1)^2} = \sqrt{26}\\
\rightarrow R\cos x \cos \alpha - R\sin x \sin \alpha = 5\cos x - \sin x \\
\rightarrow ➊\hspace{0.25cm}5 = \sqrt{26}\cos \alpha \\
\rightarrow ➋\hspace{0.25cm}{-}1 = \sqrt{26}\sin \alpha \\
$

**So here are my question(s):** $\\$

• Why is only ➊ working out?

• When I find one solution in the interval, which is 27°, why is another solution like $(360 - x)$ not working out (in this case 333°)?

• I see 310.4° as a solution to this equation in my book. How do you get to 310.4° from 27° (which is the solution I got)? Which $\cos$ identity am I missing? And surprisingly, my book doesn't include 27° as a solution!

Comment: You are missing an $R$ after the $-$ in the second arrow. The $\alpha$ is chosen to satisfy both (1) and (2).

Comment: Edited it just now

Comment: @user647486 I tried substituting the value derived from (2) into the given equation and it gave 4.9, which is wrong.

Comment: you are probably correct. Your book is wrong

Comment: You are correct. $27.019^\circ$ is also a correct answer.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes. But how is 310.4 a root? I really don't know how to get there.

Comment: I will write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
5\cos x - \sin x &=& 4\\
\frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}\cos x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}\sin x&=&\frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}\\
\cos\alpha\cos x-\sin\alpha\sin x&=&\frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Giving

$$\cos(x+\alpha)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}$$

So either

$$ x+\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}\right)=38.33^\circ $$

or

$$ x+\alpha=360^\circ-\arccos\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}\right)=321.67^\circ $$

with

$$\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}\right)=11.31$$

So you get that either $x=27.02^\circ$ or $x=310.36^\circ$.

Comment: i think you got it wrong

Comment: No, it is correct.

Comment: It is supposed to $\arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{26}})$

Comment: if it is what u took then it should be $x - \alpha$ according to the sum formula

Comment: @rash Yes, that's a typo. I will fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @rash I will put in the missing steps for you.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales So I think I forgot the fact that $\cos \theta = \cos (360 - \theta)$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my way of saying what everyone else has already said.

\begin{align}
   R &=\sqrt{1^2+5^2}=\sqrt{26} \\
   \cos \alpha &= \dfrac{5}{\sqrt{26}} \\
   \sin \alpha &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{26}} \\
   \alpha &\approx 11.31^\circ \\
\hline
   5\cos x - 1 \sin x &= 4 \\
   \cos x \cos \alpha - \sin x \sin \alpha &=  \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{26}} \\
   \cos(x + \alpha) &= \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{26}} \\
   x + 11.31^\circ &\approx \pm 38.33^\circ + n 360^\circ \\
\hline
   x &\approx 38.33^\circ - 11.31^\circ = 27.02^\circ \\
   x &\approx -38.33^\circ - 11.31^\circ + 360^\circ = 310.36^\circ
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you know why $R=\sqrt{26}$,
Hence $5\cos x - \sin x$ can be expressed as $\sqrt{26}(\frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}\cos x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}\sin x)$
$$\text{Let, } \cos\alpha = \frac{5}{\sqrt{26}} \text{ and } \sin\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}$$
Hence, $5\cos x - \sin x$ can now be expressed as $\sqrt{26}\cos (x + \alpha)$.

To solve your initial equation, we can now write it as,
$$\sqrt{26}\cos (x + \alpha) =4$$
$$\cos (x + \alpha) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}$$
$$x +\alpha = \cos^{-1} \frac{4}{\sqrt{26}}$$
If $\cos\alpha = \frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}$, then $\alpha = \cos^{-1} \frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}$,
$$x = \cos^{-1} \frac{4}{\sqrt{26}} - \alpha \rightarrow x = \cos^{-1} \frac{4}{\sqrt{26}} - \cos^{-1} \frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}$$
$$\therefore x = 27^o \text{ or } 321.40^o$$